# template function with more than 1 typename

Tags: c++, templates, type-inference

It seems C++ template can automatically deduct the type, when there is only one template parameter. For example,

```
template<typename T> 

void f(const T &t)
{
  cout << t << endl;
}

f(1);
```

is fine.

However,

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> 

void f(const T1 &t1, const T2 &t2)
{
  cout << t1 << t2 << endl;
}

f(1, 2);
```

the above code can not pass compilation. Is this because of the ability of the compiler or it is against the standard?

Comment: The compiler should be able to deduce more than one template parameters. Can you post full compilable code to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Nothing wrong with this code as far as I can tell. http://www.ideone.com/AEVs4

Comment: What happens when you remove the `&` in the parameter list? I'm getting somewhat rusty with C++, but I'm somewhat surprised to see that you can pass a integer constant (`1`, `2`) where a reference is expected.

Comment: Your code should compile (after including `<iostream>`, using `std::cout` and `std::endl`, and putting the function call inside a code block). Which compiler are you using, and what is the error message?

Comment: @stakx: It's a ref-to-const. Nothing wrong with that. Literals (as rvalues) will bind to refs-to-const just fine.

Comment: I think he didn't even try compiling it :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second function and call is perfectly valid. Your compiler is bugged or flat out old rejecting it.

Comment: As covered in comments a while ago.

Comment: @rubenvb: There is no answer to this question, as the question is flawed.

Comment: @Tomalak: He posted a question, I posted an answer. If you had an answer,you should have posted it as an answer.